Problem opening rear-camera on iOS device
I'm developing a simple app that scans qr codes and then processes them. I've made it so on Android devices, the back camera opens by using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: 'environment' } }), however this doesn't apply to iOS for some reason.
<script>
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: 'environment' } })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    var video = document.createElement('video');
                    document.getElementById('preview').appendChild(video);
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.setAttribute('playsinline', true);
                    video.play();

                    let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: video, mirror: false });
                    scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
                        var currentUrl = window.location.href;

                        if (currentUrl.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
                            currentUrl = currentUrl.split('?')[0];
                        }

                        if (currentUrl.endsWith('/')) {
                            var redirectUrl = currentUrl + content;
                        } else {
                            var redirectUrl = currentUrl + '/' + content;
                        }

                        window.location.replace(redirectUrl);

                        scanner.stop();
                    });

                    Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
                        if (cameras.length > 0) {
                            var selectedCam = null;

                            cameras.forEach(function (camera) {
                                if (camera.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('back') !== -1) {
                                    selectedCam = camera;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });

                            if (selectedCam !== null) {
                                scanner.start(selectedCam);
                            } else {
                                console.error('No back-facing camera found.');
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.error('No cameras found.');
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error al acceder a la cámara: ", error);
                });
        } else {
            alert("Tu navegador no es compatible con la API getUserMedia");
        }
    </script>

Thanks in advance for the help ^^
